# Meaning of a sentence 'I've got you under my skin'

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, translation

I'm watching a series in which it is pronounced in English: I've got you under my skin.
The translation to Spanish subtitles was:

> Te llevo bajo mi piel

The most normal translation of get is 'tener', I looked it up in the dictionary and none of its meanings are translated as

> llevar

So is it a bad translation, a set phrase or something is missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a set phrase or idiom.  If something or someone gets under your skin, it means you are constantly thinking or obsessing about that thing or person.

I cannot really speak for the quality of the Spanish translation.  Using Google translate *Te llevo bajo mi piel* comes back into English as "I wear you under my skin".  Given the metaphorical nature of the idiom in English, I guess that sort of makes sense, but I have no clue if it is idiomatic.  Presumably not, or you wouldn't be confused.

Answer (score 0):

To have someone or something under one's skin means to have a mental 'itch', an obsession, or preoccupation, towards the subject. As stated above it is often used to describe romantic feelings about someone.